# Change connection between Gmail and YouTube

Tags: gmail, youtube, anonymous

When I send people email from my Gmail account the header of the email is my YouTube name. Hence everybody can find me and my comments on YouTube. I don't want people I send mail to know who I am on YouTube!

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a new email account (using gmail or some other tool).

YouTube is implementing Google+comments.   You are not able to comment anonymously there any more.  So if you want your email to be separate, you will have create the separation at that end.